# Why does pdfplumber yield no data?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, pdfplumber

I usually use **pdfplumber** to **scrape** data and text from pdfs, and 99.99% of the time, everything is fine.

Though today, I have encountered a case where i **can open** the pdf file (using pdfplumber.open), **but not extract any text / word / table**. I know the opening is successful because it recognizes the right number of pages the pdf is containing, but using any method to get data results in getting an empty list. There is **no protection** whatsoever on the pdf file.

The .pdf files are not scans. It would seem they are generated with **XML source files**, but I don't know if it would make any difference at all since it results also in a **.pdf** file.
I also tried several other pdf scrapers leading to same results.

An interesting fact is that after using **online tools to *repair*** (I don't really know what it does to the file to be quite honest), I manage to open and extract all the text I want from it. The same thing happened when I converted the .pdf into a **.pdf/a** file.

Does anyone know a way to get around this issue, or even what causes it?

Please note that i cannot share the pdf files because they are confidential, nor reproduce such conditions as I do not know how it happens.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Not really, but I found out that it is a company named Serensia who produced these pdfs.

Comment: I didnt know Factur-X but after looking a bit about it I guess it is pretty much the same. For info, the documents I am referring to are from big energy supplier companies.

Comment: No, i am only speaking about big european companies as I am currently working in France, though this case only happened to me once. It still might be a random folder that has been corrupted or damaged. The (not so) final decision I made was just to repair them via online tools, and will see in the future if it happens again.